# How to scale SVGs that use real world units

Tags: css, svg

I need to generate SVGs using real world units (e.g. inches) and have them scale proportionately to fit inside a div with fixed dimensions. Is this possible?

As a simple example, this SVG is overflowing the div's boundaries:

```html
<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px;">
    <svg width="60in" height="15in" viewBox="0 0 60 15" style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <line x1="30" y1="0" x2="30" y2="15" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2px" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use real world units...what's the use case for that since SVG will scale to any directed size?

Comment: Sure, you can write `div svg {width:100%; height:auto;}` in your stylesheet. But I have a feeling that would be too easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the width and height attributes from your SVG (they're not necessary). Then your SVG will scale automatically to your DIV's size. (Keep the viewBox since that will remind you that your dimensions are probably in inches)

Comment: Thanks, this ended up working fine. Not sure why this issue confused me as much as it did.